# Is the dimension $-1$ the real $0$th dimension and does this all make sense?

Tags: complex-numbers, dimension-theory-analysis

I know there are at least two questions on this site that ask about the negative dimensions. But I want to ask something more than that.

We have a number line. It contains all the real numbers we can imagine of. But there are also complex numbers like (1+5i) that extend the number line into a complex plane. So, the number line that contains all possible number sets, not only the real ones is really a 2d plane, not a line.

We can say the same for a 2d graph. It contains all the real numbers on both the $x$ and the $y$ axis. But if we make the 2d function so that it can hold not only the real number pairs, but also the imaginary number pairs like (1-2i, 9+14i), we can see that a 2d graph really is a 3d graph.

Same thing for 3d. If we have an 3d pair (1+i, -5, -3-9i), then we extend the function to 4d. It is **still 3d function** because it has three coordinates. It only has complex numbers as its coordinates, which implies that 3d function has 4 dimensions.

So as we can see, (theoritecally) an $n$ dimension graph has $n+1$ dimensions.

**Is this thinking correct, and does that mean, that $0$th dimension is realy a point extended into an imaginary-only, not real-valued line, and the true $0$th dimension is the $-1$st dimension?** Does my reasoning even make sense at all?

Comment: But if each complex number is two-dimensional, shouldn't an ordered pair of them $(a + bi, c + di)$ be four-dimensional? It takes four real numbers to specify such an ordered pair.

Comment: Following @pjs36, moving to complex numbers doubles the number of dimensions.  $2 \times 0 = 0$, so taking a $0$ dimensional point (with no real coordinates) and making it a complex point (with no complex coordinates) leaves it $0$ dimensional.

Comment: Wait... does it really double? I was thinking wrong. I dont have time to edit the post now because I have to go something important, but I will edit it in couple of hours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it's nonsensical / not correct.

The notation $\mathbb{R}$ stands for the set of real numbers, and $\mathbb{C}$ for the set of complex numbers.

You are correct that $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional, and that $\mathbb{C}$ is two-dimensional. However there is no precise mathematical object that your phrase

> *"the number line that contains all possible number sets"*

refers to; if you take it to mean $\mathbb{R}$ then the dimension of the *"number line"* is 1, and if you take it to mean $\mathbb{C}$ then the dimension of the *"number line"* is 2. These facts are not contradictory in any way to each other.

But your bigger mistake is that $\mathbb{C}^2$ (the space of pairs of complex numbers) is ***four***-dimensional, not three-dimensional, and more generally,

- $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the space of $n$-tuples of real numbers) is $n$-dimensional
- $\mathbb{C}^n$ (the space of $n$-tuples of complex numbers) is $2n$-dimensional

That is because there are four "degrees of freedom" (dimensions) in choosing a pair of complex numbers:
$$(a+bi,c+di)$$
(the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ can all be chosen independently).

Note that when $n=0$, these coincide; that is, each of $\mathbb{R}^0$ and $\mathbb{C}^0$ is a single point. You can verify that $\mathbb{R}^0$ consists of the single $0$-tuple of real numbers $()$, and $\mathbb{C}^0$ consists of the single $0$-tuple of complex numbers $()$.